# import ES5 library in ES6

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to use a libary written in ES5 ([rtree](https://gist.github.com/iursevla/90b7e35b04cbcad90e12744a20b159fd)) on a ES6 project but with no luck.

On my ES6 code i do:

```
 import PolygonLookup from '../../lib/rtree';
 ...
 this.rtree = new PolygonLookup(geojson);//does not work
```

This does not work, however if i remove the import and instead add the rtree on a  tag to my html it works flawlessly.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="..\..\lib\rtree.js"></script>

 this.rtree = new PolygonLookup(geojson); //works
```

I tried to convert the abovementioned library to ES6 through lebab but it also won't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708545/es6-import-vs-script-src-in-html

Comment: You could transpile your ES 6 code. You could convert the library to ES 6 in about 12 seconds. You could simply access the global var that the library is almost certainly attached to. Not sure what the issue is here. Just don't use `import`.

Comment: @JaredSmith but how can i convert it to ES6? I tried lebab but it does not output anything.

Comment: By hand. Look, almost every JavaScript library in existence is released in UMD format. The UMD wrapper looks to see if `define` or `require` exist (for AMD or CJS module loaders respectively) and if it doesn't find either one it attaches the library to a global variable. Just include the script tag and get on with your day. Or remove the UMD wrapper code from the library and add an `export` statement by hand.

Comment: I think i'll use a script tag. I wanted to make it as modular as possible but this will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ES5 lib doesn't export anything in an ES6 compatible way. That's why `PolygonLookup` is undefined. You can import the library without any binding:

```
import '../../lib/rtree';
```

That way `PolygonLookup` will be the global `PolygonLookup`, just as if you included the lib with a `script` tag, **IF** it has been added as a global variable. Not all libraries do that explicitly. Otherwise you might try [script-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/) (Webpack only):

```
import 'script-loader!../../lib/rtree';
or even
import PolygonLookup from 'script-loader!../../lib/rtree';
```

If the bundler / loader of your choice supports other module formats, and the library uses one of them, then you could also use a regular ES6 import.

Comment: Couldn't make it work with the 1st or 2nd alternatives but it could be that i'm doing something wrong (either in webpack config or somewhere elese). Thanks anyway, will end up probably using the script tag.