# How to import ES5 library in angular 1.x project with babel and webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I have a Angular 1.x project, which wrote in ES6 and used `babel` to load and `webpack` to manage.

Now I would like to import a angular library but it writes in ES5, and I cannot import it directly by `import xxx from xxx`:

- [angular-actioncable](https://github.com/angular-actioncable/angular-actioncable)
- [ngCable](https://github.com/wazery/ngCable)

Because they didn't export the module. When I searched the solution from SO, the simplest way to add the non-ES6 library is to include it in `index.html` file. However, because my angular is load by `webpack`, so even I added the `<script src"xxx"></script>` to the last line of `body`, it still load before `angular`, so I need to find another way.

Another solution I found is using [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader) in webpack, but I don't know where I added code like `require("exports-loader?file!./file.js");`. Should be in `webpack.config.js`? Or in angular main js file `app.js`(ES6)?

Could anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: What *do* they export, and how (if not ES6 module format)?

Comment: @Bergi It doesn't export, you can check at https://github.com/angular-actioncable/angular-actioncable/blob/master/dist/angular-actioncable.js

Comment: Try this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784823/import-es5-library-in-es6