# JavaScript modules - moving from <script> to "import ..." can't be done for some libs?

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I was out of the loop when JavaScript got all fancy - I'm used to a `<script src="https://somecdn/stuff.js"></script>`, unsure about the package.json file, and have almost no experience with module packaging.

Sometimes I can move from a `<script src="..."` to `import {functions} from 'https://somecdn/stuff.mjs';` without an issue.  But other times it doesn't work.

Can everything be loaded through the new import statement, or are some scripts so module-unfriendly that I shouldn't bother?

To make it easier

1. I'm only on latest Chrome
2. My main script has the module tag: `<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>`

Successfully moved from script tag to import:

`import {clear, del, get, keys, set} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/idb-keyval@3/dist/idb-keyval.mjs';`

But when I try to migrate

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dexie/3.0.0-alpha.6/dexie.js"></script>`

it throws

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dexie/3.0.0-alpha.6/dexie.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

I'm assuming the "mjs" isn't the issue, as long as everything is being served as the right JS mimetype.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know when to import a package or paste it in index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689919/how-to-know-when-to-import-a-package-or-paste-it-in-index-html)

Comment: What error are you getting? I'm not seeing in that script that would be a problem.

Comment: @mchandleraz `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dexie/3.0.0-alpha.6/dexie.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`

Comment: @RandyCasburn Good checklist!  `<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>`, latest Chrome, and... ?

Comment: Your module source doesn't export anything, it can't be used as a source to import.

Comment: You can't export a script If it doesn't explicitly use the keyword `export`.

Comment: So it sounds like the answer is "if the lib you are loading doesn't have an 'export' you are SOL."

Comment: Yep, you've to find a lib which is exporting objects. See [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) at MDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only `import` things from files that `export` them.

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dexie/3.0.0-alpha.6/dexie.js` seems to only be exporting anything (by assigning to module.exports) when running in an environment where `module` is defined (i.e. Node).

When run in the browser, it just adds `Dexie` to the global object, without exporting anything.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!  I'll use a normal script tag.